# La Lematización de Spacy en castellano no es muy buena ¿Conocéis otros paquetes? Solo encuentro cosas en inglés

Tags: python, nltk, spacy, text-mining, nlp

Estoy empezando a analizar unos textos en castellano y veo que la utilización de spacy para el castellano por mis pocas nociones que tengo de análisis sintáctico y morfológico no es muy bueno.
Os enseño el código que he hecho y os enseño el output:

```
import spacy
import es_core_news_sm
sp = es_core_news_sm.load()

total_lemmas=[]
for i in range(len(clean_tokens)):
    sentence7 = sp(clean_tokens[i])
    for word in sentence7:
        print(word.text + '  ===>', word.lemma_)
        lemmas=word.lemma_
        total_lemmas.append(lemmas)

for i in range(len(clean_tokens)):
    sentence7 = sp(clean_tokens[i])
    for word in sentence7:
        print(word.text,  word.pos_)
```

Y os enseño un ejemplo de cada output:

```
Mucha  ===> Mucha
mano  ===> manir
,  ===> ,
mucha  ===> mucho
técnica  ===> técnico
en  ===> en
productos  ===> producto



oírlo PROPN
```

¿Conocéis algún otro paquete para texto en castellano?

Un saludo y muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es un problema común, aparte de la complejidad del NLP , por desgracia los buenos modelos suelen ser para el Ingles...

Hace muy poco que acaba de salir a la luz [Stanza](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/stanza/) (Universidad de Stanford). No he tenido oportunidad de testearlo a fondo todavía y no se lo pulido que estará el modelo en Español, pero parece prometer bastante, además de disponer de modelos para 66 idiomas actualmente.

Alguna pruebas mediante [Google Collab](https://colab.research.google.com/):

```
import stanza

stanza.download('es')
nlp = stanza.Pipeline('es')

doc = nlp('El ama de llaves abrió la puerta')

for sent in doc.sentences:
    for word in sent.words:
        print(f'word: {word.text} \tlemma: {word.lemma}')
```

> ```
> word: El      lemma: el
> word: ama     lemma: ama
> word: de      lemma: de
> word: llaves  lemma: llave
> word: abrió   lemma: abrir
> word: la      lemma: el
> word: puerta  lemma: puerta
> ```

```
doc = nlp('Mucha mano, mucha técnica en productos. oirlo')

for sent in doc.sentences:
    for word in sent.words:
        print(f'word: {word.text} \tlemma: {word.lemma}')
```

> ```
> word: Mucha     lemma: mucho
> word: mano      lemma: mano
> word: ,         lemma: ,
> word: mucha     lemma: mucho
> word: técnica   lemma: técnica
> word: en        lemma: en
> word: productos lemma: producto
> word: .         lemma: .
> word: oir       lemma: oír
> word: lo        lemma: él
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Te sugiero que te asegures de estar usando la versión 3 de spacy. He hecho una prueba con las mismas palabras que has usado tu y este es el resultado que he obtenido yo:

```py
import spacy
import es_core_news_lg
sp = es_core_news_sm.load()

print("spaCy version: ", spacy.__version__)

print("LEMMA:")
print("====================================")

clean_tokens = ["Mucha", "mano", ",", "técnica", "en", "productos"]
total_lemmas=[]
for i in range(len(clean_tokens)):
    sentence7 = sp(clean_tokens[i])
    for word in sentence7:
        print(word.text + '  ===>', word.lemma_)
        lemmas=word.lemma_
        total_lemmas.append(lemmas)

print("")
print("")
print("POS:")
print("====================================")

for i in range(len(clean_tokens)):
    sentence7 = sp(clean_tokens[i])
    for word in sentence7:
        print(word.text,  word.pos_)
```

```
LEMMA:
====================================
Mucha  ===> mucho
mano  ===> mano
,  ===> ,
técnica  ===> técnico
en  ===> en
productos  ===> producto


POS:
====================================
Mucha DET
mano NOUN
, PUNCT
técnica ADJ
en ADP
productos NOUN
```